# Need to know the name of this anime!

Tags: story-identification, anime

There was this old anime that had the same look and animation of sailor moon. It was about a woman who could see spirits and exorcise them to the beyond. She met a dog spirit in one of the earlier episodes and has a sidekick/assistant that was sexually obsessed with her.

Comment: How old is old? Do you remember when you watched it? Maybe when it was released? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and [edit] in any additional details to help provide us with more details so we can improve our search to help you!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds llike "Mikami ghost sweeper"

> Overdevelopment and crowding in Japan has forced many of its indigenous spirits and ghosts to lose their homes. Due to problems caused by the homeless spirits, a new profession was created, the Ghost Sweepers (GS). Private exorcists for hire, they serve only the highest bidder to survive in the cutthroat corporate world. Among this, the Mikami GS Company, led by 20-year-old Reiko Mikami and her two assistants, the 17-year-old boy Tadao Yokoshima and the ghost girl Okinu, is said to be the best.

Answer (score 4):

Could this possibly be ***[Gugure! Kokkuri-san](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugure!_Kokkuri-san)***?

From Wikipedia:

> Kohina Ichimatsu is an expressionless elementary school girl who lives alone, proclaims herself to be a doll, and eats nothing but instant noodles. One day, she plays the Kokkuri game by herself and summons the fox spirit Kokkuri-san who, upon seeing her unhealthy lifestyle, takes it upon himself to become her guardian and raise her properly. Thus starts Kohina's new life of being haunted by various unique spirits.

Then we see the dog spirit/attracted to the main character:

> A dog spirit who adores Kohina because she was the only person to acknowledge Inugami when they were still a real dog. Inugami longs to have a relationship with Kohina, whether it be marriage or something sexual. This leads to Kokkuri-san and Inugami often fighting with one another.

---

Turned up by a Google search for `anime woman spirit dog sidekick`.

Comment: Sounds like a good match, not sure why this got downvoted.

Comment: @F1Krazy It's a recent anime, and the main character is not an exorcist